# keeping presentingViewController alpha at 1 when presenting popover in iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, uipopovercontroller, popover, alpha

I am modally presenting a popover on top of a label similar to the popover you see when you do a long press on a message in a chat application like whatsapp or messages. The popover does not take over the entire view and the presenting view is visible in the background.

I have used a popoverPresentationController

However, I don't want the original presentingView (the tableView for the chat) to fade when the popover is active.

Is there anyway to control this?

Comment: Do you have an answer for this already? Would like to know!

Comment: Not yet.  I guess one way would be to add a subview on top and disable userInteraction for everything underneath but I prefer to use the popover.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a presentViewController instead of a popoverPresentationController, using controller.modalPresentationStyle and controller.modalTransitionStyle to make it look as a Pop Over. I'm not sure if this is what you want, but this way you will have alpha = 1 in the parent view controller.

```
yourViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(yourViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I'm using a popover to help position the presented view with an arrow to the presentingView's frame (message bubble) from which it was presented.  So I want the arrows and positioning that the popover provides.  Very much like a long press of any of your messages on whatsapp.